# When to use Multiparameter type classes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to understand the differences between the following two definitions of a Collection type class.

With multiparameter typeclasses and functional dependencies (taken from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_type_classes));

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Eq e => Collection c e | c -> e where
    insert :: c -> e -> c
    member :: c -> e -> Bool

instance Eq a => Collection [a] a where
    insert = flip (:)
    member = flip elem
```

With only a single type parameter;

```
class Collection c where
    insert :: Eq e => c e -> e -> c e
    member :: Eq e => c e -> e -> Bool

instance Collection [] where
    insert = flip (:)
    member = flip elem
```

Both seem to compile and work ok. Are there any practical differences between the two, or any reason to favour one approach over the other?

Comment: The later typeclass works as long as the `Collection` type is polymorphic in the element type, but it won't work for collections, which have only one element type.

Comment: Why swim against the current and flip the standard order of arguments?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I just copied the example from the linked source. The argument order had already been flipped. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example where the Fundep version still works, but not the single-parameter one, is [a `Set` container](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html):

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

instance (Ord e) => Collection (Set.Set e) e where
  insert = Set.insert
  member = flip Set.member
```

An instance to the other class doesn't work because you need an `Ord` constraint. Now, you could change the definitions to

```
class Collection c where
    insert :: Ord e => c e -> e -> c e
    member :: Ord e => c e -> e -> Bool
```

But for simpler containers like lists that would merely be a nuisance, you'd like to also store non-ord types there. For Hashmaps you need yet another constraint. It's no good making those global and required for *any* collection.

Comment: Why not use an associated type synonym for the element type `type Elem c`, then declare `instance (Ord Elem c) => Collection Set.Set where`? Or per if the element type isn’t needed in the typeclass, declare `instance (Ord e) => Collection Set.Set e where`.  I’m not very fluent in Haskell, so please forgive me if this is incorrect.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII (random side remark: Unicode for ROMAN NUMBER 3 is U+2162 Ⅲ): an associated type family does make a lot of sense, in fact that's what I would probably choose if I were to implement this class. A MTPC for `* -> *` containers can be used too, but in practice this can lead into problems if the container really fundamentally depends on a particular sort of entry (as with unboxed vectors).

Answer (score 4):

Another usecase your second variant won't work for is monomorphic containers. E.g., a `ByteString` can be seen as a container of `Char`s.

It should also be noted that there is a third alternative based on type families, which is the most flexible one. Though it won't make much difference from fundeps-based one in this trivial case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

class Collection c where
  type Row c
  insert :: c -> Row c -> c
  member :: c -> Row c -> Bool

instance (Eq a) => Collection [a] where
  type Row [a] = a
  insert = flip (:)
  member = flip elem

instance Collection B.ByteString where
  type Row B.ByteString = Char
  insert = flip B.cons
  member = flip B.elem
```